# How can I turn on the hotspot in Win11 in wifi settings?

Tags: windows, hotspot

```
$connectionProfile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetInternetConnectionProfile()
$tetheringManager = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($connectionProfile)

#Start Mobile Hotspot
$tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync()
```

I use this powershell script (and the task scheduler) to enable my hotspot at startup, and it works. Unfortunately it uses *bluetooth* rather than wifi, which is annoying as I have to open up the hotspot setting again to change it.

How do I start the hotspot with the *wifi* setting active instead of Bluetooth?

Comment: Will this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833873/enable-windows-10-built-in-hotspot-by-cmd-batch-powershell

Comment: A workaround is simply to turn bluetooth off. But it would be nice to know how to force it that the connection shared is using wifi. Thank you MiG for editing my initial post. Best regards